# Plotting with experimental data

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 3 columns, time(in s), output(in V), input(in V) respectively, where by using iddata, is it correct for me to determine the ['Frequency',time] in seconds ? or should i do it in frequency (Hz).

```
time = data(:,1);
tf = iddata(data(:,2),data(:,3),'Frequency',time)
sys = tfest(tf,2)
```

By using the system identification app, after importing the output and input values and estimation using state space model it turns that that the order is 2. Is it right for to to key in [tfest(tf,2)] in this case ? Or doing it wrongly?

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: isn't frequency always measured in Hz?

Comment: @GameOfThrows I understand now , in that case I'll jsut need to remove the Frequency word and and keep time as the third label. Any idea for the system identification app ?